# New line character not appearing

Tags: c++, string

Recently I wrote some code in which I need to identify a newline character. I believed using `if(str == "")` would not return true if the character was a \n but I was wrong. If you run the following code with

```
steven 

bar
```

inside `output.txt` you will get `no text at 2` which makes no sense because there should be a newline character there. Im pretty new to programming so here is the code.(It works if i `if(str == '\n')` but im curious why the newline character isnt detected by `if(str == "")`.) Please clarify why C++ doesnt recognize the newline here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream output;
    string line;
    int i = 1;
    output.open("output.txt");
    while(i <= 3)
    {
        getline(output, line, '\n');
        if(line == "")
        {
            cout << "no text found at "<< i << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "text at " << i << endl;
        }
        i++;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: The delimiter is discarded.  Read the documentation, e.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

> `getline` [...] Extracts characters from `input` and appends them to `str` until one of the following occurs [...]
>
> b) the next available input character is `delim`, [...] in which case the delimiter character is extracted from `input`, but **is not appended to `str`**.

So the string returned for your 2nd line is empty because the `\n` delimiter is not appended to it.

---

You can confirm this behaviour by using a visible char as delimiter and checking the output :

```
output.open("output.txt");
getline(output, line, 'n');
cout << line << endl; // outputs "steve"
```

instead of `steven`, you get `steve` because the delimiter `n` is not appended.

Answer (score -2):

The double quotation marks "" is empty string. New line character is different from empty string.
Let's think in reverse, if you write

```
std::cout << "";
```

and

```
std::cout << std::endl;
```

First one will print nothing and cursor will stay at same line, while the second one will move the cursor to next line.

Comment: This has nothing to do with how ’getline’ handles line endings.

Comment: iZeusify is asking why newline character is not detected by "if (str == "")". So, I would like to point out "" (empty string) is different from "\n" (newline), but not going to discuss "getline" behavior.

Comment: But his problem is he thought they were comparing equal when they should be comparing unequal, so obviously he already knows they are not the same thing, as that is the behaviour he was expecting...